# How to center items vertically and handle overflows without cutting off content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, vertical-alignment

I've managed to successfully align items on a sidebar to the center of my screen. But when content overflows it gets cut out using this method.

Here's a snippet to demonstrate.

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}

.aligned {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Sider Header</div>
  <div class="aligned">
    <button>Item 1</button>
    <button>Item 2</button>
    <button>Item 3</button>
    <button>Item 4</button>
    <button>Item 5</button>
    <button>Item 6</button>
    <button>Item 7</button>
    <button>Item 8</button>
    <button>Item 9</button>
    <button>Item 10</button>
    <button>Item 11</button>
    <button>Item 12</button>
  </div>
  <div>Sider Footer</div>
</div>
```

As demonstrated above, the top elements in the `aligned` div get cut off when there is too much content to fit into the space - despite providing the `overflow-y: auto;` property.

If you increase the container height or remove some of the buttons, you can see that it successfully centers vertically.

How can I solve the content cut off problem while still vertically aligning the content to the center in scenarios where content doesn't overflow.

Comment: Do the`.aligned` `<div>` have to fill the available height at all times or would it be OK for it to shrink and grow with its content?

Comment: That was just my way of getting it to center items vertically, so yes it will be OK for it to shrink/grow according to its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to not actually use `justify-content: center;` on `.aligned`, but just to vertically center this container it self. For this you may use `margin: auto` like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}

.aligned {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Sider Header (potential overflow)</div>
  <div class="aligned">
    <button>Item 1</button>
    <button>Item 2</button>
    <button>Item 3</button>
    <button>Item 4</button>
    <button>Item 5</button>
    <button>Item 6</button>
    <button>Item 7</button>
    <button>Item 8</button>
    <button>Item 9</button>
    <button>Item 10</button>
    <button>Item 11</button>
    <button>Item 12</button>
  </div>
  <div>Sider Footer</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Sider Header (less content)</div>
  <div class="aligned">
    <button>Item 1</button>
    <button>Item 2</button>
    <button>Item 3</button>
    <button>Item 4</button>
   
  </div>
  <div>Sider Footer</div>
</div>
```